# Interface implemented without all methods. Why not compile error?

Tags: java, interface

Below is the code asked in a quiz, the answer to the question was "Code will Compile Successfully".
But the class DoStuff is not implementing every interface method, so why there is no error?

```java
    interface DoStuff2 
    { 
        float getRange(int low, int high);
    }
    interface DoMore
    { 
        float getAvg(int a, int b, int c); 
    } 

    abstract class DoAbstract implements DoStuff2, DoMore 
    { } 

    class DoStuff implements DoStuff2 
    { 
        public float getRange(int x, int y) 
        { 
            return 3.14f; 
        }
    } 
    interface DoAll extends DoMore 
    {
         float getAvg(int a, int b, int c, int d);
    }
```

Comment: _class DoStuff is not implementing every interface method..._ Huh? It implements `DoStuff2 ` which contains `getRange()`

Comment: Why do you think class `DoStuff` must implement all interfaces? Is it because `DoAbstract` implements `DoStuff2` and `DoMore`? If so, did you notice that class `DoStuff` implements `DoStuff2` and not `DoAbstract`? If your answer to the last question is yes. I would recommend brushing up on same basics.

Comment: @JulianBroudy Thanks , cleared my doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can see this, refering to the DoStuff class:

```
class DoStuff implements DoStuff2
```

That means that your DoStuff class must implement all the methods in the interface DoStuff2. The only method in DoStuff2 is getRange, which is implemented in DoStuff.

```
class DoStuff implements DoStuff2 
{ 
    public float getRange(int x, int y) 
    { 
        return 3.14f; 
    }
}
```

The rest of classes do not affect the DoStuff class, as it only **implements** the DoStuff2 class.

Comment: Got it man, Thank you. Will read problems more clearly from now :)

Comment: @DivyanshGoswami That's it. The question is very easy if you read it carefully.
Ps: Select this answer as accepted if you think this is the best answer.